# Can we have some indication on the front page whether or not a question has comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, homepage

Comments on a question are often a good indication of whether the question is well written (a badly written question usually gets a 'Please include some code/please expand your question' comment almost immediately).

It would be useful (to me at least!) to see which questions without answers have comments (and hence are likely to be too vague to bother reading).

Comment: I've found that's it's the other way around sometimes. Interesting questions that require some clarification before answering have long comment threads.

Comment: @JohnP: The maybe the number of comments would be useful for both of us?

Comment: I just noticed that I didn't add 'but yes, an indicator would be useful' :) I'd actually prefer if the indicator showed the rate of activity rather than just whether there was activity/no activity. Maybe a color coded icon. or a number

Comment: I disagree with this; comments are and should be incidental, not essential bits of information.

Comment: Just look at the vote counts. Note that downvoting questions doesn't cost you -1 anymore. Contribute!

Answer (score 6):

Comments should not be used as an indicator of question quality.  However, there is another feature *already built-in* that allows you to indicate this.

**VOTE**

If you see a poor question, *vote it down*.  If you see a good question, *vote it up*.  This is exactly what votes are there for.

Comment: I wasn't aware that down votes are now free (and I suspect others aren't either) so that may explain why there aren't many down votes for bad questions.